# Why do *some* ScriptResource.axd requests fail on *some* computers?

Tags: asp.net-ajax

We have a website that uses ASP.NET 4.

I have experienced the problem before where *some* ScriptResource.axd requests return 404 errors, but others succeed (on the same website!).

Now we have a strange issue where the above happens, but only on *some* computers. Other computers load the page without any issues whatsoever.

Clearing our browser cache seems to resolve the issue, but we don't want all our thousands of users to have to do the same.

Any thoughts?